# jquery 1.6.2 vanishing 1.9.1 function and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am facing this problem and just doing my work by switching either of them.

Actually my basic template has been coded in jquery 1.6.2 and now i am using some other jquery function which is based on 1.9.1 library the function gos like this :

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 

      <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(":checkbox").change(function () {
            // Toggle class of selected row
            $(this).parent().toggleClass("rowSelected");

            // Get all items name, sum total amount
            var sum = 1500;
            var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
                sum += Number($(this).parents('tr').find('td:last').text());
                return $(this).parents('tr').clone();
            }).get();

            // Display selected items and their sum
            $("#selectedServices").html(arr).find('input').remove();
            $("#total").text(sum);
        });
    });

</script>
```

now since this function is not supported by 1.6.2, when i am using 1.9.1 along with 1.6.2 like this

```
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
</head>
```

only 1.6.2 supported function is working and on removing 1.6.2,console shows me error and function supported by 1.9.1 (given above) is working fine
I want to make all the functions supported by both of them work together. How to do?

Comment: Which function  _is not supported by 1.6.2_? Your code works in both versions.

Comment: @undefined check this http://jsfiddle.net/anujay/uF2Ba/8/ u'll get the answer

Comment: That fiddle seems to work fine, and I don't see any errors in the console. What problem are we looking for?

Comment: code in the fiddle supported by version 1.9.1 but my template had been coded on 1.6.2 ,on removing .6.2 this code(in fiddle) works fine but many of the other are destroying the template,not functioning well.
i wan to use both 1.6.2 and 1.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is too use only jquery 1.9.1 (or newer).

Then to update all your scripts/functions, use jquery migrate, this will let you know what to change in your code:  http://blog.jquery.com/2013/05/01/jquery-migrate-1-2-0-released/